# CMake with makefiles: add a sound at the end of build

Tags: linux, cmake

Working under Linux on a big project taking some time to build, I would like to add a sound at the end of the build. How can I do that with CMake?

My first idea is to add a command like

```
add_custom_target(DONG ALL COMMAND aplay ${PathDong} &)
```

but I don't know how to create the dependency on all the targets (to be sure to play it after all). Is there a global target depending on all the targets defined?

Note: I need it at the end of the build, not at the end of installation (that is easy).

Comment: There is the [`POST_BUILD` option for `add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_custom_command.html?highlight=post_build#build-events). However, not available for the builtin `all` target.

Comment: @Torbjörn Nice. Make an answer from that.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi done ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a script.

The script executes CMake, and after that it plays a sound. There are several solutions for this described in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/276596/play-mp3-or-wav-file-via-linux-command-line).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment, [`add_custom_command` has an additional option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_custom_command.html?highlight=post_build#build-events) for specifying *pre*-, *post*-build and *pre-link* commands for specific targets:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET myTarget
                   POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND "my_dong_script")
```

Caveat:
It's not possible to define it for the builtin `all` target, nor for multiple targets in one go. You would have to wrap a forloop around the command.